# How can we do image and write text in box side by side just like attched pictures

Tags: graphics

[image: Image for example]

i tried to write in latex of this image format but unable to do it,Please do it,how can we set figure and write text in box side by side just like in attached image

Answer (score 2):

If you put the image in a `\box` you can get the height of it by `\heightof` from the `calc`package. Then `\parbox` can be given an optional argument to specify the height of the that box, see e.g. https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Boxes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{calc}
\newsavebox\PictureBox
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}[htb]
  \centering
  \sbox\PictureBox{%
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth,height=0.5\linewidth]{example-image}}
  \usebox\PictureBox\ 
  \fboxsep=0pt%
  \raisebox{\fboxrule}{\fbox{%
      \parbox[b][\heightof{\usebox\PictureBox}-\fboxrule-\fboxrule][t]{0.4\linewidth}{%
        \begin{itemize}
        \item Ellipse
        \item Circle
        \item Square
        \item Triangle
        \item 
        \end{itemize}%
      }}}
  \caption{How can we write this?}
  \label{fig:HowToWrite}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your valuable reply.. May i know about reducing space between lines of text in box. I know it we can use "\setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}" to reduce space in lines but its not satisfying my requirement of reducing space..  How can do more space reducing.. Please reply

Comment: The separation between items is determined by `\itemsep+\parsep`. You can set `\itemsep` negative so try `\setlength\itemsep{-\parsep}`. If that is not enough you can put whatever you like, e.g. `\setlength\itemsep{-10pt}`.

Comment: How can we write " Intel® Core®"  ....the symbol is circle with inside R......

Comment: If you have a new question you should write it as a new question. In this case you can easily search to find `\textsuperscript{\textregistered}`.